# cd into executable directory using alias

Tags: bash, shell, alias, zsh

I am trying to write an alias that allows me to the current directory to the executable directory. I have this so far, but it is appending my argument into the path..

```
alias whichcd="cd $(basename "$(dirname "$1")")"
```

Which I run like this:

```
$ whichcd test_bin
/home/user/test_binfinal_path
```

The `test_binfinal_path` is the appendage of the argument `test_bin` and the final path that `which` produce.

Comment: What is `$filepath`? Also, when I copy your alias and run `whichcd test_bin`, I get  `bash: test_bin: No such file or directory`. Can you double-check that it says `/home/user/test_binfinal_path` for you when you use `alias whichcd="$(basename "$(dirname "$filepath")")"`, and if it doesn't, update your post?

Comment: i mistyped the alias.. it takes the first argument which is `$1`

Comment: Don't use an alias, use a function. The problem with your alias definition is that the alias is expanded at definition time. The problem with your design is that aliases don't take arguments. So **use a function instead**.

Answer (score 4):

There are three problems:

1. With double quotes, the `$(..)` runs when you *create* the alias, and not when you *run* it.
2. Aliases can't use positional parameters like `$1`.
3. From your description it sounds like you wanted `dirname`+`which` instead of `basename`+`dirname`

So use a function:

```
whichcd() {
  cd "$(dirname "$(which "$1")")"
}
```

Now `whichcd ls` will take you to `/bin` because that's where `/bin/ls` is.

Answer (score 0):

I won't re-explain the things that @that other guy already explained.

I have this very same but I'm using realpath in addition to what has already been said `man realpath`, in case `which boo` points to a directory where `boo` is actually a symlink and the real `boo` is somewhereElse, it `cd`s to somewhereElse

```
goto () {
    cd $(dirname $(realpath $(which $1)))
}
```